# Problem regarding the boundedness of a ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I was trying to solve the following problem and I am stuck at one point. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Suppose that for a continuous function $f(t)$ we are given that the equation

$$x'=\pmatrix{1 && -3\\2 && -4}x+f(t)$$

has at least one solution $\varphi_p(t)$ which satisfies

$$\sup\{\varphi(t)\,|\,\tau\le t<\infty\}<\infty$$

Show that all the solutions of the above ODE satisfy this boundedness condition.

I found the solutions of the homogeneous part which is

$$\varphi(t)=\pmatrix{ -2e^{-2t}+3e^{-t} && 3e^{-2t}-3e^{-t}\\
-2e^{-2t}+2e^{-t} && 3e^{-2t}-2e^{-t}}$$

After that I don't know what to do. Here $\varphi_p$ implies particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of the nonhomogeneous system can be written as a sum of the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous system and a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous system:
$$
x(t)= \varphi(t)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
C_1\\C_2
\end{array}\right)+\varphi_p(t);
$$
$\varphi_p(t)$ and $\varphi(t)$ are bounded, thus, $x(t)$ is bounded for any $C_1$, $C_2$.